# Vertically aligning text characters

Tags: rendering, uv

I am trying to get all my text, to appear, on the plane. As you can plainly see by the picture, that is not the case.

Am I making too much of it, and this is the way it is? I would like all the letters sitting on the plane

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Letters like J or P hung below the rest of the "regular" text](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/99485/letters-like-j-or-p-hung-below-the-rest-of-the-regular-text)

Comment: Hi. Please do not ask the same question twice. If you have more information to add, edit the original question and it will potentially be reopened.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand your question. That is just how most fonts work.

There is a base line where all characters sit; some glyphs extend below it, called descender, just like some extend above the base line height, depending on the font family.

[image]

If you don't want the font the way it is, either exchange font files, manually modify the font, or just edit the object to match your desired shape.

In Blender you can convert the text object into something editable like a bezier curve or mesh. If it still is am original text object, then convert it to a bezier curve and move the letters down or up as desired; otherwise if you already converted to a mesh just enter *Edit Mode* and adjust as desired.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, will try that, some of the tutorials I have been trying, just look odd with them that way. I will give what you said a try. Thank you!